# How to access elements of an external page if that page is loaded into a div using load function?

Tags: jquery, dom, load

I am loading an external page into a div using jQuery and making that div to popup. Somehow I managed to do all these. The problem here is, I have a close mark in the page that was loaded externally but I wanted to access it from the current page. It is not working if I give it in the normal way like

```
$('#close').click(function (){
// code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of .click() or put your present code on page load

```
$('#close').live("click", function (){ 
   // code here
});
```

Comment: but that present code is too big, that's why I am trying to load it externally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation my situation was that I used to use

```
   $('#close').live("click", function (){ // code here});
```

But as I was developing a single page web application, it caused a big mess. What I actually did later was to put up all my commonly used jQuery in a separate .js file, and include it in every page load and now it works just fine.

And I changed the live click to

```
$('#close').click(function (){ // code });
```

same as you have done.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question